# Div only stretches to browser-window height, not page height

Tags: stretch, css

I have been having a big problem with my webpage for a long time now and hope I can find an answer to my problem with your help. I want a div that contains the content of my pages (which varies in length depending on the individual page) to stretch the length of my page, but it only stretches the length of the window. Here's the HTML and CSS:

HTML (I only included the very basic structure):

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="content">
<div id="..."></div>
<div id="..."></div>
<div id="..."></div>
<div id="..."></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 10px;
color: #000000;
background: #FFF url(../../images/body.png) no-repeat center 40px;
margin: 0;
position: relative;}

.container {
height: 100%;
width: 960px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
position: relative;}

#content  {
width: 939px;
min-height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 210px;
left: 6px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #666;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #666;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #666;
background-color: #FFF;}
```

I tried to set the content div to overflow: auto, but that includes a scroll bar for the content div that I do not want. Am I missing anything? I thought min-height would work, but it doesn't! Does anybody maybe see where the problem lies?

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Okay, thanks to some of the comments here, I worked a little more on it, and have some more information that might help solve the problem. I noticed that <html>, <body>, <container>, and <content> all have an automatic height of 0px, so if I don't specify any height it doesn't stretch to include the other divs inside. However, if I position all these divs "relative," it does stretch. Then, however, the positioning gets all messed up. Can I change the positioning to maintain my current layout somehow?

Answer (score 4):

Your content div is in `position: absolute`. When in `absolute`, elements exit the normal flow of the page, meaning they can't be placed or streched relative to their parents, only relative to the window.

Comment: Thank you, that is great info, I didn't know that. So how can I retain the placement of the content div but have it stretch relative to the parent div? Simply changing the position to 'relative' didn't work (sorry if this was obvious...).

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements should only be used for very specific cases, like showing a modal popup in the center of the current display.  It's not useful for everyday adjustment of element positions.  Remove the position rule altogether and you should see better results.

Comment: @DanielHagemeier If you really need to have it in absolute position, you could use Javascript to resize it. Other than that, placing it in `position: relative` and changing its left and top attribute to place it where you want may get you the intended result.

Comment: @DangerMonkey: I tried changing it to 'position: relative' and the placement was perfect but the stretching still stopped at window-height...

Comment: @DanielHagemeier Is the container div streching farther or does it also stop at window height? Because if I look at your css, there is no fixed height or height values that go over 100%.

Comment: @DangerMonkey The container div is stretching farther, I can see all the content but it doesn't have the background and shadow of the content div. I'd like to keep the two separate if possible, however, to retain my current set-up with a menu, etc.

Comment: @DanielHagemeier It might be because every height is set at 100%. If your body is set a 100% initialy, it will strech only to window-height. Then, your container div is also set at 100%, so it too will strech at window-height. Finally, your content div set his min-height at 100%, meaning it will inherit his height from the container div which also inherit from window height set by the body. If you want `height: 100%` to work correctly, you'll have to set a fixed height to the body.

Comment: @DangerMonkey Hm, okay, but how would I then make sure that the page stretches with the content without leaving a lot of white space at the bottom. If I put a fixed number for the height of the body, my page stretches to that height and doesn't stay flexible to the height of content div. Is there a way to keep the page flexible like that. If I set a max-height for the body, for example, it doesn't display my content div background anymore...Thank you for your help, I really appreciate the input!!!

Comment: @DanielHagemeier Hum, I understand why you wouldn't want a fixed height. Have you tried putting `height: auto` in your container div? This might just fix your problem.

Comment: @DangerMonkey. Nope, that doesn't work either. It doesn't show my content div in that case. Is there away to hide excess white page if I went with a fixed page height?

Comment: @DanielHagemeier I tried some things with JSFiddle, I don't know if its right since I don't know what kind of content or menu you have on your page but you could try this: put `height: auto` on both `.container` and `#content`. Place `position: static; margin: 210px 0 0 6px;` in `#content`. Then see what this do.

Comment: @DangerMonkey Nope, didn't work either. One more thing, interestingly it works with overflow: auto, the #content expands to show the shadow and background-color but then it includes the scroll-bar that I don't want. Thank you again for your help, though. Any more ideas? This should be possible, right!?

Comment: @DanielHagemeier It is possible, but I think the problem is somewhere else. With what you gave me and the modification I implented, it worked for any amount of content I put in the `#content` div (meaning it expand according to the amount of content). Is there something else on your page that might act on the positioning?

Answer (score 0):

try to add `bottom: 0;` to content div. it works for me. i had very similar layout in one of my projects.